# Counting number of strings which contain two $a$'s which are not next to each other

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here is the question

> Consider strings of characters, each character being $a$ or $b$, that contain exactly two $a$’s and
>   these two $a$’s are not next to each other. Let $S_n$ be the number of such strings having length
>   $n$. Which of the following is true for $n ≥ 4$?
>
> The four possible answers are
>
> a) $S_n = \binom{n}{2}$
>
> b) $S_n =\binom{n}{2} - n - 1$
>
> c) $S_n  = \binom{n}{2} - n$
>
> d) $S_n = \binom{n}{2} - n + 1$

I got $b)$ for my answer by converting $a$ to $0$ and $b$ to $1$ then writing out all possible bit strings. Why is the answer $d)$ in this case?

Comment: Well, the "cheater's" way to do it is to write out all such strings for the case n=4, and then eliminate the impossible answers.  So we have:  abab, abba, baba, so that $S_4=3$.  Observe that $_4C_2=6$ so that (a) is eliminated.  Then $_4C_2-4-1=1$ so that (b) is eliminated.  Also $_4C_2-4=2$ so that (c) is eliminated.  That leaves (d).

Comment: @Steven Please tell us how you got b).

Comment: I got B by counting the number of bitstrings which satisfy the condition by hand. I must have made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose the two positions for the $a$'s. Of these, $n-1$ pairs are next to each other ($\{1,2\}, \{2,3\},\ldots\{n-1,n\}$) so these have to be discarded. We are left with $\binom{n}{2} - (n-1)$ options, which indeed is answer $d$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\overbrace{\underbrace{\dots}_{x_1}a\underbrace{\dots}_{x_2+1}a\underbrace{\dots}_{x_3}}^{n}.$$
Hence we have to count the non-negative integer solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+1+x_3=n-2.$$
Then use [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two): $\binom{n-1}{2}=\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n-1}{1}=\binom{n}{2}-(n-1)$.